# In VirtualBox Ubuntu on Windows host can I specify that the Ubuntu guest uses the same MAC address as the host machine?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm on a secure network and when a non-authorized MAC address is plugged in the switch kills the network port and after a brief lecture IT resets it.  VirtualBox seems to assign a different MAC address to the Ubuntu guest image which is causing a security violation.

Is there a way to force the guest Ubuntu and VirtualBox to use the same MAC address as the Windows host to avoid this problem?

Comment: If you leave it in NAT it should work fine.  Bridged mode will introduce the new MAC.  NAT creates its own internal network that is not transmitted on the network.

Comment: It is in NAT, but that still sets off the switch.  Can I assign it the same MAC as my host machine?

Comment: Something's weird there.  I have the same security at my job and if I leave it is NAT, it doesn't pick it up and works fine.  Once I set it to Bridged, it gets blocked.  Also, if you set the MACs the same, the switch or network will not know where to send the packets to.

Comment: It doesn't set off the switch immediately or consistently, but it will happen after some period of use (usually a few hours) and I asked IT to show me the MAC address and it was a different, weird one.  It occurred during virtualbox use after I was using it for about an hour.  No other machines were sharing a connection

Comment: ...if we plug in an unauthorized laptop it kills the port instantly.

Comment: You can always try going into the Network settings of your VM, clicking on the Advanced and putting in the Mac Address of your Windows system minus the `:`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please ref this 
http://ccm.net/faq/40897-virtualbox-how-to-refresh-the-mac-address-of-a-virtual-machine
NAT will not send ethernet frame with new MAC address. Please check weather the network uses other security setup like Network Access Control(NAC).

Comment: If I transfer the guest image from another machine, will it use the old MAC address?  That could be it.

Comment: yes it does and the old MAC must also be active, that could be the reason for lock out

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the link directly in your answer (citing the link as a source), so it will be available even if the link dies. Thanks!

Comment: I think I fixed it by giving the guest the same address as the host...